# Xcode 5 Ghost error

Tags: objective-c

I am getting an error But I am not sure why I am getting it. It wants a '(' before else.

Here is the whole thing.

```
#import "TweetCell.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation TweetCell

@synthesize tweetLabel = _tweetLabel;

@synthesize userImage = _userImage;

@synthesize usernameLabel = _usernameLabel;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContentCell";

    TweetCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *currentTweet = [self.tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDictionary *currentUser = [currentTweet objectForKey:@"user"];

    cell.usernameLabel.text = [currentTweet objectForKey:@"name"];

    cell.tweetLabel.text = [currentTweet objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.userImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSString *userName = cell.usernameLabel.text;

    if ([appDelegate.profileImages objectForKey:userName]) {
        cell.userImage.image = [appDelegate.profileImages objectForKey:userName];
    }

}


else {

        dispatch_queue_t conccurentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(dispatch_get_global_queue, 0);
    dispatch_async(conccurentQueue, ^{
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[currentUser objectForKey:@"image.png"]];

        __block NSData *imageData;

        dispatch_sync(conccurentQueue, ^{

            imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

            [AppDelegate.profileImages setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] forKey:userName];

        });

    });
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see the code *before* the opening `else`, not after it. (This code looks syntactically correct.)

Comment: Closing curly bracket before else seems to close the method, thus else is outside of any method. Looks like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Move the bracket before the else to the end of the method

Answer (score 0):

Change your else and bracket placement to the following:

```
if ([appDelegate.profileImages objectForKey:userName]) {
    cell.userImage.image = [appDelegate.profileImages objectForKey:userName];
} else {
    dispatch_queue_t conccurentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(dispatch_get_global_queue, 0);
dispatch_async(conccurentQueue, ^{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[currentUser objectForKey:@"image.png"]];

    __block NSData *imageData;

    dispatch_sync(conccurentQueue, ^{

        imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

        [AppDelegate.profileImages setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] forKey:userName];

    });

    });
}
```