# Objective-c Error. Xcode not sure what is wrong with code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

It is giving me an error saying i am missing an @end, unexpected @ in the program, and it wants a closed bracket all at the end of the code.

```
#import "TweetCell.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation TweetCell

@synthesize tweetLabel = _tweetLabel;

@synthesize userImage = _userImage;

@synthesize usernameLabel = _usernameLabel;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContentCell";

    TweetCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *currentTweet = [self.tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDictionary *currentUser = [currentTweet objectForKey:@"user"];

    cell.usernameLabel.text = [currentTweet objectForKey:@"name"];

    cell.tweetLabel.text = [currentTweet objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.userImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSString *userName = cell.usernameLabel.text;

    if ([appDelegate.profileImages objectForKey:userName]) {
        cell.userImage.image = [appDelegate.profileImages objectForKey:userName];
    }
    else {
        dispatch_queue_t conccurentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(dispatch_get_global_queue, 0);
        dispatch_async(conccurentQueue, ^{
            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[currentUser objectForKey:@"image.png"]];

            __block NSData *imageData;

            dispatch_sync(conccurentQueue, ^{

                imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

                [appDelegate.profileImages setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] forKey:userName];
        });

    });
    }
@end
```

Comment: *"... and it wants a closed bracket all at the end of the code"* - Then why don't you add it? With the automatic indenting in Xcode, it is actually quite easy to find matching (or non-matching) brackets.

Comment: He also never creates a cell.

Comment: and actually it is a double post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669637/xcode-5-ghost-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the method, return the `UITableViewCell` like so:

```
return cell;
```

Comment: I love you guys, the best community!

Comment: first he must create a cell

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing bracket.  Add one before the @end

Comment: now it says "control reaches end of non-void function" when I add that bracket. Not sure what to do.

Comment: You need to return an instance of UITableViewCell

Comment: non-void function = method that returns something. Can be nil.

Comment: Just type in return cell; at the end of the method

Answer (score 0):

How to find your mistake:

- Select All
- Copy
- Paste

This will cause Xcode to reformat your code as it pastes it back.

You should notice your `@end` is indented after this - and this is because you've an opening brace without a matching close one.

Add the brace. (And you can check again with the command-A, command-C, command-V sequence.)

HTH